# Is the image of a weakly convergent sequence also weakly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

This question comes from my thinking on the learning of functional analysis. Suppose that $S:L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is an operator.Suppose that  $f_n$ is convergent weakly to $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lVert S(f)\rVert \leq M\lVert f\rVert$ for any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.Can we show that $S(f_n)$ converges to $S(f)$ weakly in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.I think it is right,but I don't know how to show it.If it is not true,could you offer some example?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right. I have rewritten it,do you think it is appropriate now?or could you give suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how you defined weak convergence. I assume that it means
$$
\phi(f_n) - \phi(f) \rightarrow 0
$$
for every bounded linear functional $\phi:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Note that $\phi \circ S$ is a bounded linear functional, since both $\phi$ and $S$ are bounded and linear. It follows that
$$
\phi(S(f_n)) - \phi(S(f)) = (\phi \circ S)(f_n) - (\phi \circ S) (f) \rightarrow 0.
$$

Note that this also works for every Banach space and not only $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes，you are right. I missed the boundedness of $S$.